# Displaying FirstViewController's data on a UITableView in SecondViewController

Tags: ios4

I'm new to iPhone app development. My requirement is:

In my `FirstViewController.xib`, I have 2 `UITextField`s. I want to display that two text fields' data on `UITableView` in `SecondViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have a button to navigate in SecondViewController. When button is tapped you should navigate to SecondViewController.

Here you can pass those two text fields data in array when button tapped and assign that array to SecondViewController's object.

The FirstViewcontroller button tap event may look like as follows.

```
-(void) buttonTapped
{  
    SecondViewController *svc = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:textField1.text,textField2.text,nil];
    svc.tableData = arr;
    [self presentModalViewController:svc animated:YES];       
}
```

Have a property tableData in SecondViewController.

```
@interface SecondViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSArray *tableData; // contains array of data to be displayed in tableview 
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *tableData;
@end
```

your tableview delegate methods may look like this.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    // Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];            
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Best of Luck.

Comment: Hi,Thanks Dude.It's Working.But i need small change,i want to display both textfields data in single cell.

Comment: Its simple. just add both the textfield values into a string and add that string to array.